# Twitter Friendship/create api asking for authentication in swift

Tags: swift3

I am trying post a follow the user but am still not able to hit post api POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=1401881&follow=true.

it is  showing :

> Error: Optional(Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=220 "Request
>   failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Twitter
>   API error : Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.
>   (code 220), TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=403,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=12345&follow=true,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403)})

this is my code :::

let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient()

```
    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=852067343241027587&follow=true"
    //let params = ["user_id":"\(userId)","follow":"true","screen_name": "Deploables1"]
    var clientError : NSError?

    var request = twitterClient.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: nil, error: &clientError)
    request.addValue("Bearer \(twitterAccess)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")

    request.addValue("client_credentials", forHTTPHeaderField: "grant_type")
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    twitterClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) in
        if connectionError != nil {
            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
        }else {

            do {
                print("response ::\(response)")



                let json:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                print("json: \(json)")



            } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
            }





        }
    }
```

can anyone help me out for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is clear, it says that you do not have credentials, please show your code.

Comment: let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient()
        
        let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=852067343241027587&follow=true"
       
        var clientError : NSError?
        
        var request = twitterClient.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: nil, error: &clientError)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(twitterAccess)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")

Comment: twitterClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) in
            if connectionError != nil {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }else {
                
                do {
                    print("response ::\(response)")

Comment: add your code on your post [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43580804/edit)

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple way to follow user with his/her twitter id or screen_name:

func gettingFollowUsingSLComposerTwitter() {

```
let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
let twitterType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: twitterType, options: nil,
                                     completion: { (isGranted, error) in
    guard let userAccounts = accountStore.accounts(with: twitterType),
        userAccounts.count > 0 else { return }
    guard let firstActiveTwitterAccount = userAccounts[0] as? ACAccount else { return }

    // post params
    var params = [AnyHashable: Any]() //NSMutableDictionary()
        params["screen_name"] = "Deploables1"
        params["follow"] = "true"

    // post request
    guard let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter,requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.POST,
                                                                      url: URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"),
                                                                      parameters: params) else { return }
    request.account = firstActiveTwitterAccount

    // execute request
      request.perform(handler: { (data, response, error) in
    print(response?.statusCode)
    print(error?.localizedDescription)

      })
})

}
```